# Failed to open file "/media/$USER/pendrive/keyfile" No such file or directory

Tags: linux, embedded-linux

I'm editing **/etc/crypttab,** to access the keyfile from USB. The USB has been mounted to "**/media/my_username/pendrive"** But I can't figure out how can I open "**my_username**" directory.

My etc/crypttab:

data1 /dev/sdb /media/"$USER"/68F5-35A4/keyfile luks

I can open this:
data1 /dev/sdb /media/srikanthpendem/68F5-35A4/keyfile luks

But I want use $USER or $USERNAME or whoami commands instead of my computer name.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61584927/edit) your question to provide some [MRE] in your question. Inside kernel code (or a device driver) you cannot open any file. Files make sense only in user land. Read a [textbook on operating systems](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) then [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/)

Comment: For userland programming, use [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) and, if you need it, [getenv(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getenv.3.html). Maybe you need [opendir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html) then [readdir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html)

Comment: the `linux-device-driver`  and `linux-kernel` tags seems inappropriate and confusing. Please remove them

Answer (score 1):

> I'm editing `/etc/crypttab`

To edit a file, use a good [text editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_editor), such as [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) or [vim](https://vim.org/) or [nano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_nano).

> But I want use $USER or $USERNAME or whoami commands instead of my computer name.

To edit a file in a shell script, consider using in your script some utilities such as [sed(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sed.1.html) or [GNU ed](https://www.gnu.org/software/ed/), in your case you might also need [printf(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/printf.1.html) and/or perhaps [awk(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/awk.1.html).

Alternatively, write a small userland program (e.g. in C, or in some scripting language such as [Guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/), [Python](https://python.org/), [Lua](https://lau.org/), etc...) which does what you want. For that you'll use system calls listed in [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html).

Since there is no way to programmatically *insert* bytes in the middle of your file, your userland program will generate a new `/etc/crypttab`  file and overwrite the old one. Don't forget to backup it.

Read of course the [documentation of GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/index.html). Notably the section on [shell expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html).

Be of course aware that [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) cannot be done in kernel land. Because they are the main interface of the kernel to user land application code. Read [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) then [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/) then some [textbook on Operating Systems](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/).

Avoid any kernel programming if you don't understand very well system calls and application programming.